# Lower bounds on growth of the abundancy index distribution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, probability-distributions

Let $a(n)=\sigma(n)/n$ be the [abundancy index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) of $n$ and let $F(x)$ be the distribution function of this index: i.e., the proportion of integers $n$ with $a(n)\leq x$. (This function is well-defined and continuous for the abundancy index, though that's very non-trivial). [Erdős proved](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1974-19.pdf) an upper bound of the form $F(x+\frac1t)-F(x)<C/\log(t)$ and showed that this is best possible, and also proved that $F(1+\frac1t)-F(1) \in (1+o(1))e^{-\gamma}(\log t)^{-1}$, but I'm interested in the values of $F(x+\frac1t)-F(x)$ for larger $x$, and interested in inequalities the other direction: is anything known about *lower* bounds for $F()$ in this more general case?